# Converting an ArrayList<someObjects> to an HTML table

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

I have a couple of ArrayLists with variable length and sometimes null. This ArrayList contains a bunch of objects. 
The table should have columns based on (some) attributes of the object. And the table should be displayed on a jsp.

I have two ideas, one is to use a JSTL tag the other is to use JavaScript. And library suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You're confusing JavaScript with JSP scriptlets.

Comment: No actually I was referring to JavaScript, but Stephen P (below) has already clarified that JavaScript does not have access to Java Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSTL is better**,

Javascript you should avoid as much as possible ,

I am not sure how you are going to render datatable using java script and Collection

How to use jstl with collection that has been demonstrated by Bozho in the same thread.

Comment: Why should avoid JS as much as possible? If there's already a dependency on JS, JS can give you a data grid with many more features than jstl (html alone). All you'd need is to pass the List<Object> as JSON. You could use something like Ext-JS grid for sortable, filterable, reordable hideable columns... http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html

Comment: @Juan Mendes If its possible to do with JSTL avoid js because javascript will load browser also not as much reliable. and the case OP is talking about is best suited using JSTL

Comment: life.java Your argument doesn't make much sense to me. If your site must work with JS disabled, that may be true, otherwise, your comment sounds like someone who doesn't know much JS. I, for example, require JS since all the interaction is AJAX based. Even if JS is not required, The grid I suggested also supports progressive enhancement. You could output the table with jstl and enhance it to be sortable, filterable, if the client supports JS.

Comment: Can we do this thing if the data is to be parsed in diff rows (in 1 loop) as opposed to the normal column flow parsing..

Comment: @testndt can you elaborate it a bit

Comment: Sure..like normally when you are iterating through the loop, we are filling tabe cells or rather diff columns within the same row in each iteration...My question is can we do this parsing for different rows in a column for each iteration..there may be many wotkarounds...

Comment: You can create your own custom tag to put your custom parsing logic

Answer (score 1):

JSTL is the standard, preferred way (unless you need to load it via ajax, for example)

```
<table>
<tr><td>Foo header</td><td>Bar header</td></tr>
<c:forEach items="${yourRequestScopedArrayList}" var="obj">
    <tr>
       <td>${obj.foo}</td>
       <td>${obj.bar}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: I think it should be items with an s.

Comment: When I run the code <td>${obj.getItemID()}</td> its telling me that "The function getItemID must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified". What can I do?\

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are just fields on the target object. I used the standard names not knowing what your object looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have access to the Java objects that live (I presume) on the server. The server code can make the ArrayLists available to the JSP which can then loop over them with a JSTL `forEach` tag.

How you make the ArrayLists "available" depends on the framework you're using, but the plain servlet way is just setting an attribute from the doPost method.

```
request.setAttribute("list1", arrayList1);
```

The loop would be something like

```
<table>
<tr><th>Column 1</th> <th>Column 2</th> <th>Column 3</th></tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${list1}">
    <tr><td>${row.col1data}</td> <td>${row.col2data}</td> <td>${row.col3data}</td></tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```